# Divider component not found in Android Jetpack Compose project

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, divider

I'm currently working on an Android UI entirely Compose based.
I need to put a Divider component between 2 lists implemented as LazyColumn (vertical) and LazyRow (horizontal).

When I try to use the component, IntelliJ cannot suggest any dependency reference for Divider:

[image]

I already use the "androidx.compose.material" for other components in the UI and these are correctly imported:

[image]

I even tried to add the reference manually using the import but nothing is found:

[image]

Just for completeness, this are all the gradle app dependencies I actually use in the project:

`

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha01'
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
```

`

Any suggestion how to solve ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a dependency

```
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your dependencies you are using **M3**:

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha01'
```

In this case to use the `Divider` composable you have to import the right package:

```
import androidx.compose.material3.Divider
```

and pls note you cloud switch to stable `1.0.0` or `1.1.0-alpha01`.
If you want to use **M2** (`androidx.compose.material.Divider`) you have to add the dependency

```
implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.0")
```